# Upgraded To 18.04 -> USB Harddrive doesn’t idle anymore

Tags: upgrade, usb-drive, idle

I upgraded my Homeserver from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS and sadly my backup harddrive attached through USB doesn’t get into idle mode anymore. 
This harddrive is just used to backup every night so it should idle/suspend the whole day...

hdparm output:

```
$ sudo hdparm -y /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
 issuing standby command
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 01 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Any suggestions? On 16.04 it was just working out of the box.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having this problem too, on a Seagate Backup+ Hub. Can you see the SMART data for the drive in gsmartcontrol? I used to be able to do that, and the upgrade broke that too. (Also zfs is very upset with the drive's zpool.)

Comment: This may be caused by [Bug #1781769 "hdparm on USB drive , SG_IO error after update 17.10 to 18.04"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hdparm/+bug/1781769)

Answer (score -1):

looks like autosuspend has not been installed

```
sudo apt-get install autosuspend
```

Comment: Does Autosuspend works like this? This is a server so the server shouldn’t suspend on inactivity, just the Harddrive (normally hdparm / hd-idle) I think hdparm is the standard package to provide that but unfortunately after the upgrade the usb drive doesn’t spin down

Comment: @Blakkmaan Autosuspend does not depend on X11 and desktop environments and is therefore specifically intended for (home) servers. Most available checks address these usage scenarios.

Comment: @karel x11-Common is a dependency?!